# Server specifications for extensive data mining

Tags: memory, data-mining, specifications

I am running a data mining project that parses a RDF dataset of around 2 GB to generate graphs (around 100 mb) and saves  as python pickle.

Sadly, my current Dell poweredge with 4GB RAM can't save the graph due to limited memory (memory error). I have tried other ways to save it like gml or plaintext or adjacency but seems like I need more RAM I suppose.

Should I just go ahead and buy a good server with around 12GB RAM, or will other factors speed up the parsing and search (like multicore ? using multiple threads in script? ).

If it's the h/w, can you please suggest some good server models to buy as I am not very adept at dealing with hardware specs. My budget is around $3500.

Answer (score 0):

Data sets that are 2GB large with output that's around 100MB is not really huge.  If you have 4GB of physical RAM and swapping enabled, you should not get an out of memory error due to physical hardware constraints.

What software are you using to process your data and render your result?  What OS are you on?  It could be more a limitation of / bug in the software that you are using that you get an out of memory condition when exporting.

Comment: @ Eric ... I am using NetworkX on Python. Parsing runs fine, but when I try to save or write the graph it gives a memory error. The server is running on Ubuntu 10.04. The error is like:                    Error: 
>  pickle.dump(G,fh,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)   
> MemoryError                                                                                                                    ........... So other discussions had lead me to believe it was exceeding the machine's memory